# Как парсить вложенный тег <sup>

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

День добрый. При парсинге html таблицы не получается уложить в список содержание вложенного тега "sup". Исходный html со страницы (http://gosjkh.ru/company/sverdlovskaya-oblast/kamensk-uralskij) выглядит так. [image: исходный код]

Пытаюсь парсить его следующим образом:

```
def get_mc_list (html):
    print("====== Работет функция get_mc_list ======")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
#    tag = soup.find('th', class_ = 'col-md-1')
#    tag.th.decompose()
    c_list = []
    print('Переменная c_list сейчас выглядит так', c_list)
    for i, row in enumerate(soup.html.body.table.findAll("tr")):
        for cell in row.findAll("th"):
            c_list.append(cell.string.strip())
            print ('\t\tIn tr & th loop c_list\n')
            print ('\n\t\t\t'.join(c_list))

    return c_list
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
  <ipython-input-19-fe703cc2d18d> in get_mc_list(html)
     50     for i, row in enumerate(soup.html.body.table.findAll("tr")):
     51         for cell in row.findAll("th"):
---> 52             c_list.append(cell.string.strip())
     53             print ('\t\tIn tr & th loop c_list\n')
     54             print ('\n\t\t\t'.join(c_list))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Это заголовок таблицы и обозначение квадратных метров там в superscript. Пробовал просто удалить данные этого тега из разбора, но тоже не получается. Как отбросить данные этого тега из разбора или получить их в формируемый список c_list вместе со строками тега "th"? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вам надо получить текст в теге `th` вместе с текстом вложенного тега `sup`? Или отбросить тег `sup` вместе с содержимым?

В первом варианте:

```
for cell in row.findAll("th"):
    text = cell.text.strip()
```

Во-втором чуть сложнее:

```
for cell in row.findAll("th"):
    text = cell.find(text=True, recursive=False)
    if text:
        c_list.append(text.strip())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я рассматривал для себя тот и другой вариант. Теперь ищу, что такое за атрибут "recursive" ))

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Если `recursive` будет `True`, то в результат попадёт и текст вложенного тега `sup`.